# image to barcode recognition

Tags: mobile, barcode, barcode-scanner, image-recognition

I know this has been discussed a few times on stackoverflow but I wasn't able to find a sufficient answer. For a project, I am seeking the best possible piece of software/api/library  that can recognise barcode numbers from the  input image. It will be used on mobile phones(iphone, windows mobile, android etc.) so it should be good at catching barcodes from bad angles, blurry images and such bad conditions. Being open source or commercial doesn't matter as long as it does the job well (indeed open source would be better :) )

If you have any experience with this topic, please share with us:)

Thanks

Comment: Out of the question, but are you familiar with QR Codes and Semacodes?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semacode, might be useful if you're also generating the codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has an Open Source project for this [zxing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

I'm familiar enough with it to know if it will do everything you need it to do, but I imagine it would be a really great place for you to start.

Comment: zxing does not work with blurry images

Comment: Granted, but as with any image recognition software, there are thresholds as to how good of a sample image is needed in order for it to work. This is exactly why CAPTCHA images will be intentionally blurred, malformed, and have added noise to the image. If it can be helped, of course try to supply the sharpest image possible, but I think it's a bit much to expect any IR software to be able to perfectly recognize images regardless of poor sample quality.

Answer (score 3):

see http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/

Comment: Do you know how well zbar performs compared to zxing?

Comment: zbar perfoms better then zxing